# Is there any option where we can put all the respected email in that table header which is an array?

Tags: javascript, html

I have table with 4 headers and a array of mixed email id , how can i insert this using only JavaScript any idea?

```
<html>
<body>
<table>
<tr>
  <th>Gmail</th>
  <th>Hotmail</th>
  <th>Yahoo</th>
  <th>Others</th>
</tr>
<tbody>

</tbody>
</table>

<script type="text/JavaScript">
data= ["multiple emails with different domain name"];
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please add sample data or describe desired output it is not clear what you want

Comment: You need to `forEach` array then substring for return which domain is then create `<tr>` and `<td>` for append result.

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/JavaScript">
let data = [
  'one@foo.co',
  'two@gmail.com',
  'three@hotmail.com',
  'four@gmail.com',
  'five@yahoo.com',
  'six@bar.co'
];

let list = document.querySelector('table tbody');

let mapper = {
  gmail: 0,
  hotmail: 1,
  yahoo: 2
};

data.forEach(email => {
    let row    = document.createElement('tr');
    let domain = email.match(/(?<=@).+(?=\.)/);
  let index  = mapper[domain];
  
  row.innerHTML = '<td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td>';
  
  if (typeof index === 'undefined') {
    index = 3;
  }
  
  row.children[index].innerText = email;
  
  list.append(row);
});
</script>
```

Demo here [link](https://jsfiddle.net/vu8k7xbr/3/)

Comment: Yes, Done a Great Job just that it gives a empty space now wherever the for loop has run extra.

Comment: Just wrap your first heading `tr` inside `thead`
please check [link](https://jsfiddle.net/87jabo9y/)

Comment: But it is still the same no changes taken place on the cells

Answer (score 0):

Unable to edit @Sonjoy Samadder solution, so adding new answer with his code refactored.

```js
let data = [
  'one@foo.co',
  'two@gmail.com',
  'three@hotmail.com',
  'four@gmail.com',
  'five@yahoo.com',
  'six@bar.co'
];

let list = document.querySelector('table tbody');

const groupedMails = data.reduce((acc, mailId) => {
  const domain = mailId.match(/(?<=@).+(?=\.)/);
  (acc[domain] || acc.others).push(mailId);
return acc;
}, {gmail: [], hotmail: [], yahoo: [], others: []});

addDataToTable(groupedMails);

function addDataToTable(groups) {
    const maxRows = Object.values(groupedMails).reduce((e1, e2) => (e1.length > e2.length ? e1 : e2).length);
    const colOrder = ['gmail', 'hotmail', 'yahoo', 'others'];
    const tableEle = document.querySelector('table tbody');
    tableEle.innerHTML = '';
    for ( let i = 0; i < maxRows; i++) {
        const tr = colOrder.reduce((acc, key) => {
            const td = document.createElement('td');
            td.innerText = groups[key][i] || '';
            acc.append(td);
            return acc;
        }, document.createElement('tr'));
        tableEle.append(tr);
    }
}
```

```html
<table>
<thead>
<tr>
  <th>Gmail</th>
  <th>Hotmail</th>
  <th>Yahoo</th>
  <th>Others</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody></tbody>
</table>
```